# Delete username in comments Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How can I delete my username or initial in comments in Excel with help of VBA code? I know I can change the usernamne, but even if I leave username option box empty, it still shows a colon in bold, when I open a new comment. I want the comment box to be blank. Is that possible?

Comment: [This article](https://www.contextures.com/xlcomments02.html) explains how to change the username in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This website has a few options you could try. They have code for removing comments and formatting the comments using a VBA macro. I see one where it allows you to post a comment without a user name. Did not try it myself, but looks promising.

[Contextures.com/xlcomments03.html#Name](https://www.contextures.com/xlcomments03.html#Name)